# Undefined method `javascript_link_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im sure this is simple to fix but i've been on the problem for 2 hours now.

All im trying to do is load my User Index View which has a boostrap table. In the view i have it loading some JS files.

When i try to try to access it through my broswer i receive this error.

Anyone have any clues how to fix it and have the JS files load?

**undefined method `javascript_link_tag'**

Here is my User Index View

```
<%= javascript_link_tag 'dataTables.bootstrap.js' %>
<%= javascript_link_tag 'jquery.dataTables.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_link_tag 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %>


<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%= @user.username %> <small>Edit Items</small></h1>
</div>


<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @item.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
          <td><div class ="small_fifty_image"><%= image_tag item.image.url(:thumb) %></div></td>
          <td><h4><%= link_to item.title, item_url(item.id) %></h4></td>
          <td>$<%=item.price %></td>
          <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><%= link_to "Edit Items", edit_item_path(item) %></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><%= link_to "Delete", item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no such method `javascript_link_tag`. According [to the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag) you should use `javascript_include_tag`. This method allow you to generate link tag for the individual scripts in your assets path as well.

Also, please note that files provided by gems usually don't include version in the file name and they aren't minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Add in *application.html.erb*:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= yield :javascript_includes %>
```

In top of your *View.html.erb*:

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>  
  <%= javascript_include_tag "dataTables.bootstrap.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.dataTables.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Everything in the `content_for` block will be loaded at `yield :javascript_includes`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'dataTables.bootstrap.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.dataTables.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %>
```

instead.

Comment: yeah i tried that doesn't load. :( <%= javascript_include_tag :all  %> makes the js work though. But i cant use that code...

Comment: why you can't use `javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js'`

Comment: @joeyk16, please be more descriptive in what goes wrong.